# Find index of element comparing with sorted vector

Tags: r

If I have a sorted vector, like

```
vec <- c(5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14)
```

and I have

```
x <- 9.5
```

Then `x` is between the 5th and 6th value in my sorted row, and I want to get the index 5. How can I do it?

Comment: What should be the output if we replace `x` above with 9? 5 or 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will give the result you're looking for:

```
x<-c(5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14)
findInterval(9.5,x)

> [1] 5
```

Alternative solutions include:

```
> max(which(x < 9.5))
[1] 5
```

Answer (score 1):

There should be multiple ways to do this. One way using `which.max`

```
which.max(vec > x) - 1
#[1] 5
```

This finds first index where `vec` is greater than `x` and then returns an index 1 less than that.

As it is sorted the opposite should work as well

```
which.min(vec < x) - 1
#[1] 5
```